# timer calling activity after back button is pressed

Tags: java, android, timer

I am trying to make simple maths game. Aim of the game is to answer so many questions right in a certain time limit.

I have a timer which counts down and calls my final screen to set your highscore. Problem is, when testing the app if the back button is pressed before timer is done, it seems to continue in the background and my highScore screen randomly appears. How can I make this stop?

Here is the code for my timer:

```
/**
 * timer method
 */
public void timer() {

    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


        }

        public void onFinish() {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HighScoreScreen.class);
            i.putExtra("Score", score);

            startActivity(i);
            resetScore();
            finish();


        }
    }.start();

}
```

Comment: Cancel the timer in `onBackPressed`?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this very particular problem would be to override `onBackPressed` and cancel your timer there. On the other hand, if you want to cancel the timer when there is any interruption (e.g. user receives a call while using your app), you could perhaps place the cancel call in a lifecycle method like `onStop`.